# Split HTTP GET request into multiple parts

Tags: java, apache, http, get, httpclient

I use Apache HttpClient (version 4.5.1) to send GET requests from my application to a remote server which does not supported long requests (URL limit is 2000 characters).

How can I split a request into multiple parts?

In this example I want to split the next URL into 2 different URLs:

```
Source:
http://testdomain.com/people/names?param1=2007&param2=[{"Code":"1","Text":"Test1"},{"Code":"2","Text":"Test2"}]

Result:
http://testdomain.com/people/names?param1=2007&param2=[{"Code":"1","Text":"Test1"}]
http://testdomain.com/people/names?param1=2007&param2=[{"Code":"2","Text":"Test2"}]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you sure you cannot use a POST request instead with a body?

Comment: @regilero yes, remote server does not supported POST requests.

Comment: @Paul You should probably reconsider the format of your `param2` if possible. It doesn't look very URL-friendly...

Comment: convert your json to a object (with JSON.prase()) and loop throw your object and call each URL you need.